# Installation of metadata-extractor

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I'm stuck on installation.
I downloaded Maven, but I'm not sure which file within 
the metadata-extractor folder (that I downloaded from the repo) to use as the target.

I tried all the files at the top level.
All attempts have failed, e.g.

> java -jar metadata-extractor-2.13.0.jar build.gradle
>
> *com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException: File format could not be determined*

I am using v2.13.0 of the meta-data extractor

Answer (score 0):

I've just started to code and took interest in this project but also had issues using it. Instead of using Maven i just downloaded the source code from github and threw the 'com' folder into my myproject/src folder. Then i downloaded the xmpcore-6.1.10.jar library and added it to the Build Path. Got it working that way. I hope someone will give you a better solution but if you just wanna do something right away, you can try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading IntelliJ and create a "new project from version controll". Use the URL given on the GitHub page (under download/code). That will save you a lot of problems.